# Google Sign In - Failed to resolve 'Auth'

Tags: android, libgdx, firebase, google-authentication

I'm trying to integrate the new Google Sign In 9.0.0 with LibGDX. But for some reason the 'Auth', 'GoogleSignInResult' and some other classes are missing.

[image]

Using build script dependency: `'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`
and android dependency: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0`

My android dependencies:
[image]

I have those classes using classpath dependency: `'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5''`
and android dependency: `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'`

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the text formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new Firebase 9.0.1 this issue got resolved!